# split string - multiple delimiter C++

Tags: c++, string

so this user input all in one line string , i need to parse the input into two categories: user age and user name.
for example , the user input -->> [23:Frank] [15:Jack] [45:] [33:sofia] []
in this case i have more than one argument (delimiter, total of 3 ) which are [:] , in addition i need to get user input and stop looping once i encounter the [] at the end.

this is what i was thinking :

```
string input;
vector<string> age;
vector<string> name;

cin >> input;
while (input != "[]")
{
    get age between first [ and :
    assign to age variable
    get name between : ]
    assign to user name variable
    ................
}
```

also - what if one of the brackets is missing a name , how can assign a blank name and skip that part in order to process the rest (meaning i will output age with no name next to it).
any suggestions regarding how to get and process the data.
i saw some advance stuff like Toknizing and booster which are advance for my course, that's why i was thinking about straight forward getline and parse functions.
Thank you.

Comment: Not going to do your homework for you, but I would read one character at a time, and build a state machine, with states like waiting for [, parsing age until colon or ], parsing name until ], waiting for [...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in token like you are currently doing with cin

test for [] as you are doing with the while loop

For the inside the loop, here are a few things to help you out:

1. `std::string`'s `front` and `back` functions are perfect for ensuring that input starts with [ and ends with ]
2. `std::string`'s `substr` function is perfect for trimming off the [] so you can easily ignore them for the rest of the parsing
3. `std::stringstream` allows you to call make a stream that only contains your trimmed input.
4. `std::getline(stream, string, char)` will read all characters it finds up to the `char` parameter or the end of the stream and stuff the results in the string parameter and then discard the `char` it found so you won't trip over it parsing the rest of the input.
5. `strtoul` will convert a string into a number and tell you if it failed. It will not accept negative numbers so you can catch people trying to trick your program.
6. `getline(stream, string)` will read the stream until it hits an end of line marker. Perfect for reading the rest of a stream that contains no end of lines.

Using strtoul:

```
char * endp;
unsigned long agenum strtoul(agestr.c_str(), // turn string into old c-style string
                             &endp, // will be updated with the end of the char after the last number 
                             10); // base ten numbers
if (endp != '\0') // old c-strings always end on a null (numerical zero). If strtoul 
                  // didn't end on a null, the string wasn't a valid number.
{
    //not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so THANKS for people who helped or at least tried to help!!

what i end up doing for this part was as follows:

1. read in each string at once
2. use the `find` function in order to locate my delimiters ( which are in this case [ : ] )
3. return positions per each perimeter based on my argument (each pair will hold either the beginning and the end for age || name)
4. pass those arguments results to truncate the string by using `substr` function, then assign into each variables.

   ```
     while (true) 
    {
       string myInput;
       cin >> myInput;
       while (myInput != "[]")
        {
          int age_beg = myInput.find('[') + 1 ;
          int age_end = myInput.find(':', age_beg);
          string age = myInput.substr(age_beg, (age_end - age_beg));

          int name_beg = age_end + 1;
          int name_end = myInput.find(']', name_beg);
          string name = myInput.substr(name_beg, (name_end - name_beg));

          cout << "NAME : " << name << " AGE : " << age << endl;
          cin >> myInput;
       }
    }
   ```

Hope this will help others with the same question in the future !!